# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Node deployment Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a node express, react application on aws's ElasticBeanstalk. But the application deployment fails during the npm install on the instance.

> Upload Complete. 2018-12-22 20:12:20    INFO    Environment update is
>   starting.       2018-12-22 20:12:23    INFO    Deploying new version
>   to instance(s). 2018-12-22 20:12:48    ERROR   Failed to run npm
>   install. Snapshot logs for more details. 2018-12-22 20:12:50    ERROR 
>   [Instance: i-0a7458ff1bef89f9a] Command failed on instance. Return
>   code: 1 Output:
>   (TRUNCATED)...opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line
>   180, in npm_install
>       raise e subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.14.1-linux-x64/bin/npm',
>   '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1.  Hook
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed. For more
>   detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
>   2018-12-22 20:12:50    INFO    Command execution completed on all
>   instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1]. 2018-12-22 20:12:50
>   ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s)
>   'i-0a7458ff1bef89f9a'. Aborting the operation. 2018-12-22 20:12:50
>   ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
>                                                                          ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.

```
package.json
{
  "name": "express-react-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "boiler plate node + react app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nodemon node server/app.js",
    "start:test": "NODE_ENV=test node server/app.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=prod node server/app.js",
    "format": "prettier es5 --single-quote --write '**/*.js'",
    "format-check": "prettier-check es5 --single-quote --write '**/*.js'",
    "react:watch": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "react:build": "webpack --mode development",
    "dev-env": "npm-run-all --parallel start:dev react:watch",
    "test:server": "npm run format-check && ava server/tests/* --verbose",
    "test:client": "npm run format-check && ava client/tests/**/*.test.js --verbose",
    "test:client:watch": "npm run format-check && ava client/tests/**/*.test.js --verbose --watch --coverage",
    "test": "npm run format-check && ava */tests/**/*.test.js --verbose",
    "coverage": "nyc npm run test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@callstack/react-theme-provider": "^1.0.7",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "browser-env": "^3.2.5",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-status-monitor": "^1.2.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "pino": "^5.8.1",
    "pino-pretty": "^2.2.4",
    "prettier": "^1.15.2",
    "prettier-check": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-intl": "^2.7.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sinon": "^7.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "create-ava": "^2.0.1",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.6",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "nyc": "^13.1.0"
  },
  "ava": {
    "babel": {
      "testOptions": {
        "presets": [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          "@babel/preset-react"
        ]
      }
    },
    "require": [
      "@babel/register",
      "@babel/polyfill",
      "./client/tests/config.js",
      "./client/tests/helpers/browserEnvironment.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong with the deployment.

The logs say something about python 2 not found but I am not sure if that's the problem. Here are the logs for the reference

> ------------------------------------- /var/log/eb-activity.log
>   -------------------------------------   gyp verb cli [ '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.14.1-linux-x64/bin/node',
>   gyp verb cli
>   '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
>   gyp verb cli   'rebuild',   gyp verb cli   '--verbose',   gyp verb cli
>   '--libsass_ext=',   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',   gyp verb cli
>   '--libsass_ldflags=',   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]   gyp
>   info using node-gyp@3.8.0   gyp info using node@10.14.1 | linux | x64 
>   gyp verb command rebuild []   gyp verb command clean []   gyp verb
>   clean removing "build" directory   gyp verb command configure []   gyp
>   verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
>   gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2   gyp verb `which`
>   failed     at getNotFoundError
>   (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)   gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at F
>   (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)   gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at E
>   (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)   gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16   gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5   gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5   gyp verb
>   `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)   gyp verb
>   `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2   gyp verb `which`
>   failed     at getNotFoundError
>   (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)   gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at F
>   (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)   gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at E
>   (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)   gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16   gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5   gyp
>   verb `which` failed     at
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5   gyp verb
>   `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)   gyp verb
>   `which` failed   stack:   gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not
>   found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError
>   (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n
>   at F (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n
>   at E (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)\n
>   at /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n
>   at /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n
>   at /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at
>   FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)',   gyp verb `which` failed
>   code: 'ENOENT' }   gyp verb check python checking for Python
>   executable "python" in the PATH   gyp verb `which` succeeded python
>   /usr/bin/python   gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c
>   "import sys; print "2.7.15   gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" %
>   sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j   gyp verb get node dir no
>   --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 10.14.1   gyp verb command install [ '10.14.1' ]   gyp verb install input
>   version string "10.14.1"   gyp verb install installing version:
>   10.14.1   gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed   gyp verb install version is already installed,
>   need to check "installVersion"   gyp verb got "installVersion" 9   gyp
>   verb needs "installVersion" 9   gyp verb install version is good   gyp
>   verb get node dir target node version installed: 10.14.1   gyp verb
>   build dir attempting to create "build" dir:
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node-sass/build   gyp ERR!
>   configure error    gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied,
>   mkdir '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node-sass/build'   gyp
>   ERR! System Linux 4.14.77-70.82.amzn1.x86_64   gyp ERR! command
>   "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.14.1-linux-x64/bin/node"
>   "/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
>   "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="   gyp ERR! cwd
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node-sass   gyp ERR! node -v
>   v10.14.1   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0   gyp ERR! not ok    Build
>   failed with error code: 1   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):   npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
>        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE   npm ERR! errno 1   npm ERR! node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`   npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1   npm ERR!    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.10.0
>   postinstall script.   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
>   npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:   npm ERR!     /tmp/.npm/_logs/2018-12-22T20_12_48_626Z-debug.log   Running npm
>   install: 
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.14.1-linux-x64/bin/npm
>   Setting npm config jobs to 1   npm config jobs set to 1   Running npm
>   with --production flag   Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for
>   more details.   UTC 2018/12/22 20:12:48 cannot find application npm
>   debug log at /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log 
>        Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in 
>         main()
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
>         node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
>         self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
>         raise e   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.14.1-linux-x64/bin/npm',
>   '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1
>   (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
>
> [2018-12-22T20:12:48.669Z] INFO  [4110]  - [Application update
>   app-6694-181222_201205@3/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/50npm.sh] :
>   Activity failed. [2018-12-22T20:12:48.669Z] INFO  [4110]  -
>   [Application update
>   app-6694-181222_201205@3/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity
>   failed. [2018-12-22T20:12:48.669Z] INFO  [4110]  - [Application update
>   app-6694-181222_201205@3/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
>   [2018-12-22T20:12:48.670Z] INFO  [4110]  - [Application update
>   app-6694-181222_201205@3] : Completed activity. Result:   Application
>   update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed [2018-12-22T20:17:12.316Z] INFO 
>   [4490]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
>   [2018-12-22T20:17:12.316Z] INFO  [4490]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore]
>   : Starting activity... [2018-12-22T20:17:12.316Z] INFO  [4490]  -
>   [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
>   [2018-12-22T20:17:12.316Z] INFO  [4490]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] :
>   Starting activity... [2018-12-22T20:17:12.316Z] INFO  [4490]  -
>   [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a permission problem:

`gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node-sass/build gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/node-sass/build' gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.77-70.82.amzn1.x86_64 gyp ERR! command "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.14.1-linux-x64/bin/node"`

I'm not sure why that is happening - do you need sudo access?

Comment: I am pretty new to aws. If you mean sudo access in aws cli, then no. If sudo in some other place, I am not sure how to provide sudo access.

Comment: Let's put it this way - you are getting a 'permission denied' error, which shouldn't be the case in /tmp... - that is where npm is doing the work of building your npm modules and resolving dependencies before putting them in place. Perhaps some other process running as root has left things behind that get in your way, or the user you are running at has pretty much no permissions. If you can work out the cause of this failure, you are most of the way to fixing it.